# Module parse failed:You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: angular, typescript

Please forgive me if the question is very simple. I have just started learning Angular. 
I am trying my first app. But it does not compile. Because it does not recognize part of my code. 
I was wondering if somebody can give me some hints on what I am doing wrong in here?

app.component.html file:

```
<!--The whole content below can be removed with the new code.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{pageTitle}}!!
  </h1>
  ... Starter Files ...
</div>
```

app.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-root',
  template: <div><h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1></div> // **this line of code created error**  
})
export class AppComponent {
  pageTitle: string = 'Angular: Getting Started';
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Acme Product Management</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <pm-root></pm-root>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the error : [image]
would you please give some help on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have backticks or quotes in your template:

> The template is a multi-line string within ECMAScript 2015 backticks
>   (`). The backtick (`)—which is not the same character as a single
>   quote (')—allows you to compose a string over several lines, which
>   makes the HTML more readable.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'pm-root',
      template: `<div><h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1></div>` // **added backticks**  
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      pageTitle: string = 'Angular: Getting Started';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick help, Iingthe. It is compiling now

Comment: @user1836957 Please do accept the answer so that it will help future readers as verified answer